# Is it possible to use js resources on Node.js or react Native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/

Is it possible to use this api, player and methods, in a node.js or react native app?

Sorry for the basic question, but I'm a SQL / Web developer, and I need to know about the mobile app part to think about the backend part.

Comment: The resource is web js resource. So you can only use it on web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the module at the address you are linked to if you are running the function through a `webview`, or you should use the `React-native` module to resolve this through the `React-native`.

[This link](https://github.com/Myagi/react-native-vimeo) is a '`vimeo`' module used by the React-native.